# Simple HTML dom - finding an element above another

Tags: php, dom

I'm using PHP Simple DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/),

So far I've managed to do what I want with it, however I'm attempting to get some text of the first element with a certain class above another.

My issue is that the divs aren't nested in the area I need to get the information from. Like so:

```
<div class="day">Sunday<div>
<div class="game">...</div>
<div class="game">...</div>
...
<div class="day">Monday<div>
<div class="game">...</div>
<div class="game">...</div>
...
```

Each game has a title, time, channels.. So whilst I'm gathering all of that in to my array I want to be able to find the first `class="day"` in order to add it to my array.

`$html->find('h2.time_head')` is how I'm currently getting the day heads, but I'm not sure how I can match it up to my games, as I'm getting them `foreach($html->find('div.blockfix') as $div)` like so.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you do something like `$div->find...`?

Comment: I'm already using something like that, but I need the div before the game div.

Comment: @JakeEvans you want day for each `<div class= "game">` ?

Comment: @fusion3k yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If above HTML sample is the content of `<div class="blockfix">`, you can retrieve corresponding day in this way:

```php
foreach( $html->find('div.blockfix') as $block )
{
    foreach( $block->find('div.game') as $div )
    {
        $day = $div;
        while( $day = $day->prev_sibling()  )
        {
            if( $day->class == 'day' ) break;
        }
        if( $day ) echo $day->__toString();
        else       echo 'no day found';
    }
}
```

I leave your basic `foreach` because I don't know if you do some other stuffs, but if you prefer you can perform a unique foreach:

```
foreach( $html->find('div.blockfix div.game') as $div )
```

The core of code is the use of `->prev_sibling()`: we check each previous sibling of current “game” `<div>` until we found “day” class.

Comment: Okay, I'm always getting the first date now. I'm off to work but here's my code http://pastebin.com/MQvTLeTp - Site I am pealing from is http://liveonsat.com/los_soc_br_eng_ALL.php. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JakeEvans your pastebin in no longer available, and in html source I can't find any game class

Comment: I have fixed my issue, turns out the rest of the divs had a different class than the first one. Thanks for your help.